# NetBeans doesn't show git ignore files

Tags: netbeans

I can't see my project's .gitignore files within my netbeans program.

Is there a way to make them appear within the list of files? I could not find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the NetBeans Options
- Click on the 'Files' tab
- Under 'Ignored Files Pattern', the default is:

  `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$`
- This means that, by default, NetBeans ignores all files beginning with '.' except for .htaccess
- You can update this regex to the following to also exclude .gitignore:

  `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|gitignore)$).*$`
- Click OK, and NetBeans will immediately begin displaying your .gitignore files.